# Introducir en una variable de bash cada una de las líneas del comando ls

Tags: linux, bash, variables

Usuario convencido de GNU Linux, a mi edad estoy aprendiendo a programar en bash (o intentándolo).
Pretendo introducir en una variable cada una de las líneas que arroja el comando ls, para procesar cada una de ellas posteriormente en un bucle for.
He revisado man de awk, grep, y algún comando más, tratando de separar el output de ls por el fin de línea, \n, pero no soy capaz.
¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: No veo la manera de ser más explícito. Lo que pretendo es procesar la salida de ls mediante un pipe (|) con otro comando (¿Cuál, es mi duda?) que me separe cada línea que arroja ls, para introducir cada uno de esos valores en una variable: variable = `ls | comando.desconocido [opciones]`

Comment: algo así: while read LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done < <(ls -l)

Comment: Sería interesante que explicaras cuál es la finalidad de todo esto. Parsear la salida de `ls` es bastante peligroso, pues puede haber casos en los que la salida no sea "limpia" (véase [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/40596) por ejemplo). Si lo único que quieres es ir operando sobre cada fichero de un directorio, puedes hacer `for fichero in *; do ... cosas con "$fichero"... done`. Pero insisto, necesitamos más detalles sobre qué es lo que quieres hacer con estos datos.

Comment: Efectivamente, @fedorqui, la idea es operar sobre cada fichero de una misma extensión (eso ya lo tengo filtrado). Tomo nota de tu apunte, interesante, y leeré el enlace que propones en cuanto tenga tiempo.

Comment: GuardabosqueS entonces lo que propone @B.Pato en la primera parte de su respuesta es lo único que necesitas. `for fichero in *.txt; do ... cosas con "$fichero" ... done`, por ejemplo para ficheros txt.

Comment: a cual comando??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para procesar linea a linea la salida de `ls`

```
# Haciendo uso del comodin * como comenta @fedorqui
for file in *
do
    echo "$file"
done

# Esta forma ejecuta el bucle en el ambito del script y ls en una subshell
while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
done < <(ls -l)

# Esta forma ejecuta ls en el ambito del script y el bucle en una subshell
# por lo que las variables solo existen en esa subshell
ls | while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
done
```

Como curiosidad ya que no es relevante para la respuesta como apunta también @fedorqui
`ls` tiene la opción `-1` que imprime por pantalla los archivos linea a linea.

```
ls -1
```

Comment: No hace falta `1` para este caso. `ls` ya devuelve los datos uno a uno, como puede verse por ejemplo con `while read li; do echo "$li --"; done < <(ls)`. De todos modos, no es necesario una process substitution de estas, pues un mero `for file in *; do ... done` ya hace lo mismo y de forma más segura.

Comment: Anda, no sabia que se podía usar el * para esto, lo tendré en cuenta, comenté lo del parametro 1 porque se me vino a la cabeza pero supongo que tienes razón y solo los imprime de forma legible por pantalla.

Comment: Muchísmimas, gracias, @B.Pato, me ha valido. :) Se puede dar el hilo como resuelto, además de que habéis sido muy ilustrativos, claros, y habéis expuesto más documentación que la respuesta a la propia pregunta. Gracias de nuevo.